# JOGL Textures are semi-transparent

Tags: opengl, rendering, textures, jogl

Sorry if this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to find the solution.

I've created a box that is textured by making four quads. However, when I rotate the box around to see how it rendered, the textures that should be should not be visible are displayed on the top of the other textures.

I think this has to do with the order in which they are rendered. I render the front face of the box first, so that when I rotate to the back, the front texture is displayed over the back.

I recall seeing something about 'culling' but I can't find any documentation. Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you give us a little more detail? You talk about drawing a box, but you also mention 4 faces, whereas a box typically has six. Are you sure you have drawn your faces int he right place? What happens if you just use colours rather than textures to differentiate the faces?

Answer (score 1):

First Make sure you enabled Depth test and also 'z'  values of the quads in the box are correct. Your problem seems like you are using same depth values for the quads or just having depth test disabled.

A quick search gave me this link.Hope it will help.
http://www.leolol.com/drupal/tutorials/3d-graphics-jogl-opengl-etc/jogl-lesson-4-3d-shapes-and-rotation-opengl

PS: your title for this post doesn't support your question :(

Comment: I had depth-test enabled for a 2D project, that caused them to be not transparent at all. Your comment got me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds (although looking would be better, meaning some code) rather like a depth testing issue than a culling issue. Are you sure you enabled depth testing (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`) and retrieved a context with a depth buffer?

Comment: @DJClayworth No, why should they? If you first draw the front side and then the back side, the back side will always be visible over the front side from every perspective, if depth testing is disabled. Maybe you talk about a situation, where back face culling is enabled, but first, this is not the default situation and second, back face culling should rather be used for optimization purposes than for hidden surface removal, as for the latter it only works for such simple convex objects like a cube.